# How do i clone all children from specific node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Preface: This is my first interaction with .Net and XML data manipulation.

I need help with cloning all the children form a specific node (`<MonitoringData>`) and all of it's children. There are 15 instances of the node `<MonitoringData>` that will need to be cloned. Eventually I will need to insert data from an access DB into a few of the children of `<MonitoringData>` but I'll figure that out once I get there.

XML Document looks as follows:

```
<MetaData>
<MonitoringData type="Sample">
.....few other children
<IndividualMonitoringResult>
<IndividualResult>
<MonitoringStartDate>2019-04-01</MonitoringStartDate>
<MeasurementQualifier/>
<MeasurementValue/>
<LimitOfDetection/>
<LimitOfQuantification/>
<MeasurementUnit>mg/L</MeasurementUnit>
<LaboratoryCertificationNo/>
<QCExceedance/>
<OrganicsAnalyzedDate/>
</IndividualResult>
</IndividualMonitoringResult>
</MonitoringData>
<MonitoringStartDate>2019-04-02</MonitoringStartDate>
<MeasurementQualifier/>
<MeasurementValue/>
<LimitOfDetection/>
<LimitOfQuantification/>
<MeasurementUnit>mg/L</MeasurementUnit>
<LaboratoryCertificationNo/>
<QCExceedance/>
<OrganicsAnalyzedDate/>
</IndividualResult>
</IndividualMonitoringResult>
<IndividualResult>
<IndividualMonitoringResult>
...Duplication for each day of month
</IndividualResult>
</IndividualMonitoringResult>
<MonitoringData>
....Duplication of last MonitoringData
</MonitoringData>
</MetaData>
```

This is the code I currently have. The exception I receive is 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set'

```
    Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
    xdc.Load(GlobalVariables.strXMLFileName)
    Dim strXPATH As String = "/u:eDMR/u:Submission/u:Facility/u:Report/u:MonitoringLocationGroup/u:MonitoringData/"
    Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xdc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("u", xdc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
    Dim xnl As XmlNodeList = xdc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strXPATH, nsmgr)
    For Each xnd As XmlNode In xnl
        xnd.CloneNode(True)
    Next
```

I understand that the code I've presented is intended to locate a single child of a parent and then clone it. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to grab the whole node.
I found a solution but it's in C#.
[How to make a copy of a XML node with all their child nodes and values but different name C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185463/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-xml-node-with-all-their-child-nodes-and-values-but-diffe)

Expected result would be to grab all of the children of node `<MonitoringData>` in memory to which I will then insert data into a few of the children. I'll figure data insertion out on my own. I would like help figuring out how to grab all of the children of a particular node.

Comment: The last `/` is a syntax error for the XPath expression `/u:eDMR/u:Submission/u:Facility/u:Report/u:MonitoringLocationGroup/u:MonitoringData/`

Comment: Your xml as shown is invalid.  Can you please post valid xml?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
 Try
        Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.Load(GlobalVariables.strXMLFileName)
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//MonitoringLocationGroup/MonitoringData")
        Dim node As XmlNode
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", "Monitoring Data by Monitoring Location Group:")
        For Each node In nodeList
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", node.InnerText)
        Next

    Catch xmlex As XmlException
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", xmlex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex.Message)
End Try
```